# error issue on the debugging process

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

In Eclipse®, on the Run menu, click Debug Configurations or Run Configurations.
Expand the BlackBerry Simulator item.

Perform one of the following tasks:

To work with an existing launch configuration, under BlackBerry Simulator, click a launch configuration.

To work with a new launch configuration, right-click BlackBerry Simulator, and click New.

Click the Simulator tab.
Click the General tab.
Click run

i have followed all the steps above but still i am getting the error failed to connect to the remote VM.Connection time out.org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException

can anyboby help me in this issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you see this every time you launch your test?

This [thread mentions](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/missing-net-rim-speech-data-en-US-debug/m-p/384138):

> For the 8530 simulator just try it again.
>   I get that message sometimes when I am running too many apps/low memory (I do a lot)/just started Eclipse/etc.
>   Often if I run it a second, sometimes third time it works and continues to work after that.